# Problems trying to load a PDF file inside HTML with Angular

Tags: html, angular, pdf, typescript, web-frontend

I'm having problems trying to view a pdf file inside an html page. Here's my Angular code to retrieve the file:

Service:

```js
recoverDocument(id: Number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(`url`, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob } )
      .map(response => response.blob());
  }
```

Component:

```js
 recoverPDFDocument(){
    this.documentService.recoverDocument(this.id)
      .subscribe(response => {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
        this.documentPDF = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
      });
  }
```

HTML:

```html
<object height="500px" width="100%" type="application/pdf" [attr.data]="documentPDF">
      Couldn't open PDF File.
 </object>
```

My file just wont render. No errors appear in my console.
  I noticed the url had a 'blob:' on it, so i tried to get just a substring starting on 'http'. Then this error occured:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.

Answer (score 0):

What will happen if you add link some?

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="http://youserver.com/report.pdf"></object>
```

Pdf is opened or you see Promise error?

And what data in this.documentPDF variable?